# Guardar Consulta en Variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en **Windows Form (.NET Framework)**
y lo enlace a una base de datos **SQL Server**

lo que quiero saber es como guardar el valor de una consulta en una variable
solo es un valor, un numero el que quiero guardar
La consulta es:

**SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articulo**

Y el resultado es 128

Lo tengo de esta manera:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Limpieza_1._1.BD;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Limpieza_1._1.Formularios
{
public partial class ArticulosC : Form
{
    ConexionSQL ConectarBD = new ConexionSQL();
    public ArticulosC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SqlCommand sentencia = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.CodArticulo as Codigo, a.Nombre, a.Precio_Compra as Compra" +
            ", a.F_Elaboracion as Elaboracion, a.Marca, a.Precio_Venta as Venta, a.Descripcion, p.Nombre as Proveedor FROM " +
            "Articulo a INNER JOIN Proveedor p ON a.CodProveedor = p.CodProveedor");
        dataArticulo.DataSource = ConectarBD.ConsultaSQL(sentencia).Tables[0];
    }
```

lo del datagridview funciona, pero quiero que la cantidad de registros que tengo me aparezca en un texbox

como guardo ese simple resultado en una variable para luego mostrarlo a uno o varios textboxs por favor

Comment: Tendrias que consultarlo a tu base de datos, si ya imlementaste tu cadena y todo deberia de ser facil

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Una de las posibilidades puede ser [executeScalar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). Si revisas la misma observarás que el ejemplo encaja a la perfección con lo que buscas.

Comment: Hola Rodolfo, que tienes hasta ahora implementado? muestranos un poco como haces hasta ahora la consulta. Saludos

Comment: Ya añadi el codigo para que vean como esta hecho

Comment: lee sobre executescalar

Comment: Si ya tienes las filas en dataArticulo asigna al textBox y su propiedad text el count del dataGrid. miCaja.Text = dataArticulo.Rows.Count().ToString();

Comment: dataArticulo guarda la consulta del Codigo que publique, lo que quiero en especifico es que la consulta
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articulo
del cual el resultado solo es 128, se me muestre en un textBox.

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta de realizar un executeScalar

```
public int countArticulo()
{
    Int32 countProd = 0;
    string sql =
        "Select count(*) from dbo.Articulo;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            countProd = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // manejar la excepción
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    return (int)countProd;
}
```

Desde tú código, podrías llamar:

```
public ArticulosC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SqlCommand sentencia = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.CodArticulo as Codigo, a.Nombre, a.Precio_Compra as Compra" +
            ", a.F_Elaboracion as Elaboracion, a.Marca, a.Precio_Venta as Venta, a.Descripcion, p.Nombre as Proveedor FROM " +
            "Articulo a INNER JOIN Proveedor p ON a.CodProveedor = p.CodProveedor");
        dataArticulo.DataSource = ConectarBD.ConsultaSQL(sentencia).Tables[0];
        tuTextBox.Text = countArticulo().ToString();
    }
```

Pero estás manejando las conexiones a la base de datos en una clase que **no has expuesto**, por tanto deberías de adaptar o crear un nuevo método en la clase ConexionSQL, que implemente este método.

Y aunque no es la manera adecuada, y dado que ConexionSQL(sentencia) supongo que devolverá un dataset también te funcionará esto:

```
public ArticulosC()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SqlCommand sentencia = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.CodArticulo as Codigo, a.Nombre, a.Precio_Compra as Compra" +
        ", a.F_Elaboracion as Elaboracion, a.Marca, a.Precio_Venta as Venta, a.Descripcion, p.Nombre as Proveedor FROM " +
        "Articulo a INNER JOIN Proveedor p ON a.CodProveedor = p.CodProveedor");
    dataArticulo.DataSource = ConectarBD.ConsultaSQL(sentencia).Tables[0];
    tuTextBox.Text = ConcectarBD.ConsultaSQL("Select count(*) from dbo.Producto;").Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
}
```

[Execute Scalar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)